# Load HTML files on file system with Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I'm developing a Xamarin PCL app and I need to show a HTML `index.html` file that is located on the file system (in LocalState folder), along its CSS and JS resources. The app need to work with UWP.

I'm trying with Xamarin Forms WebView but it gives me no result, the webview is empty.

I can no resolve this even because there is no Javascript Console so I can no get any error.

**The files are not located in the app assets.** Every examples I'm encountering are referring about files in Assets directory.

There's any WebView, even any plug-in WebView, that can help me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Now I get it:

For UWP local folders they usually are under `C:/Users/{USERNAME}/AppData/Local/Packages/{PACKAGENAME}/LocalState/...` so this directory for UWP WebView is the same as `ms-appdata:///local/...`. Using the last one it can import CSS and JS resources.